# Change background color of accessoryView in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell, accessoryview

I have a custom cell (not using xib), and I'm trying to change the background color of the accessory view. Here is my code and what I tried"

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    customCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellID" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.accessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    return cell;
}
```

**Results:**

The background color didn't change.

Comment: Does your cell actually have an accessory view? How did you create it.

Comment: I created it in the storyBoard

Comment: Created what? Are you talking about dragging in a control of some sort, or do you mean setting the accessory type. The latter doesn't create an accessory view. You should log cell.accessoryView to see if it's nil.

Comment: At the attribute inspector, I set the accessory type to detail. When I did an NSLog, it came out to nil. What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in either of two ways. You can change the table view's tint color, which will change the color of the accessory, or you can drag in any view or control you want, and change its color to whatever you want.